# Cursor position goes to at the start point for "contentEditable" by using dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Whenever I typing, my cursor goes to the start point. I need to use **freeAllAttributeHTML()** this function and also update the **content** .

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

function App() {
    const [ content, setContent ] = useState('')


    const freeAllAttributeHTML = (htmlString) => {
        var cleanedHtml = String(htmlString).replaceAll(/<div[^>]*>/g, '<div>');
        cleanedHtml = cleanedHtml.replaceAll(/<p[^>]*>/g, '<p>');
        cleanedHtml = cleanedHtml.replaceAll(/<span[^>]*>/g, '<span>');
        cleanedHtml = cleanedHtml.replaceAll(/<button[^>]*>/g, '<button>');
        cleanedHtml = cleanedHtml.replaceAll(/<a[^>]*>/g, '<a>');
        cleanedHtml = cleanedHtml.replaceAll(/<svg[^>]*>/g, '<svg>');
        cleanedHtml = cleanedHtml.replaceAll(/<img[^>]*>/g, '');
   
        return cleanedHtml;
    }



    const handleContentChange = (e) => {
        setContent(freeAllAttributeHTML(e.target.innerHTML))
    }


    return (

        <>
            <div>
                <strong>hello one</strong>
                <em> hello two</em>
            </div>
            <div 
                className='editable'
                contentEditable={true}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }}
                onInput={handleContentChange}
            />
        
        </>
    )
}

export default App
```

I am trying to make a custom richtext editor in react.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the purpose of the **freeAllAttributeHTML** function you defined is to clean up the HTML content by removing attributes from certain HTML tags.

Where the cursor moves to the start point every time you type may be related to the way you handle input and update content. A common problem with **contentEditable** is that the cursor position is lost when you directly manipulate the **inner HTML**.

Try this example:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');
  const editableRef = useRef();

  const freeAllAttributeHTML = (htmlString) => {
    var cleanedHtml = String(htmlString).replaceAll(/<div[^>]*>/g, '<div>');
    cleanedHtml = cleanedHtml.replaceAll(/<p[^>]*>/g, '<p>');
    cleanedHtml = cleanedHtml.replaceAll(/<span[^>]*>/g, '<span>');
    cleanedHtml = cleanedHtml.replaceAll(/<button[^>]*>/g, '<button>');
    cleanedHtml = cleanedHtml.replaceAll(/<a[^>]*>/g, '<a>');
    cleanedHtml = cleanedHtml.replaceAll(/<svg[^>]*>/g, '<svg>');
    cleanedHtml = cleanedHtml.replaceAll(/<img[^>]*>/g, '');

    return cleanedHtml;
  };

  const handleContentChange = () => {
    const newContent = freeAllAttributeHTML(editableRef.current.innerHTML);
    setContent(newContent);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <strong>hello one</strong>
        <em> hello two</em>
      </div>
      <div
        className="editable"
        ref={editableRef}
        contentEditable={true}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }}
        onInput={handleContentChange}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you sure this is working for you ? Because still it has the same problem, not working for me .